# PayPal REST error PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID

Tags: paypal

We recently had a transaction vs the live PayPal system return a 400 code with the error PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID. The message was "This request is invalid due to the current state of the payment". The information on that message in the PayPal docs isn't very helpful.

Upon getting that error, our ecom system didn't allow the customer to complete their order and could not proceed. Later we got an email from PayPal regarding the transaction. They said the payment was under review and could take up to 24 hours to release. They finally did release it the next day.  Given the error and message we received via the api call, I wouldn't have expected PayPal to continue to process the order.

Is this normal for this PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID error? Are there other error codes that will result in PayPal still processing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information on the Payment State this is found on the PayPal Developer site:

[Rest API Payment States](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/)

**state** string Payment state. Must be one of the following: created; approved; failed; pending; canceled; or expired.
Value generated by PayPal.

```
PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID
```

This request is invalid due to the current state of the payment

The payment state does not allow this kind of request.

It is possible that this happened because the payment went under review and did not send back the state of pending. Normally when a payment goes under review it is supposed to receive a payment state of pending.

Comment: I don't even understand what this means.